# Hello. I want to decrease the button-to-top scroll speed in java script. Can anyone help me with that?

Tags: javascript

I want to decrease the button-to-top scroll speed in java script. Can anyone help me with that?

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow. Please refer to the [How to ask section](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in order to create a complete and answerable question.

Comment: What is the code you are currently using to do this scroll?

Comment: function scrollFunction() {
        if (document.body.scrollTop > 20 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 20) {
            document.getElementById("myBtn").style.display = "block";
        } else {
            document.getElementById("myBtn").style.display = "none";
        }
    }

    // When the user clicks on the button, scroll to the top of the document
    function topFunction() {
        document.body.scrollTop = 0; // For Safari
        document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;// For Chrome, Firefox, IE and Opera
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> // When the user scrolls down 20px from the top of the document,
>   show the button
>           window.onscroll = function () {
>               scrollFunction()
>           };
>
> ```
>     function scrollFunction() {
>         if (document.body.scrollTop > 20 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 20) {
>             document.getElementById("myBtn").style.display = "block";
>         } else {
>             document.getElementById("myBtn").style.display = "none";
>         }
>     }
>
>     // When the user clicks on the button, scroll to the top of the document
>     function topFunction() {
>         document.body.scrollTop = 0; // For Safari
>         document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;// For Chrome, Firefox, IE and Opera
>     }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Jquery `animate` function:

```
$(`your-button-selector`).click(function(){ 
        $('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'slow');    
});
```